# The element type 'Object' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, list, dart, object, widget

```
 Stack(
  children: [
    isShowAd ? StaticFields.interstitialAd!.show() : SizedBox(),
```

He says you can not assign an object to a list type widget what should I do to resolve this issue

I want to display Interstitial ads when builder runs

Comment: could you include what inside StaticFields.interstitialAd!.show() too?

Comment: Its Whole bunch of Static Variables class

Comment: may I see them?

Comment: Whatever you put in a Stack needs to be a Widget. `StaticFields.interstitialAd!.show()` doesn't seem to return a widget. So you can't use that there. I don't know what kind of interstitialAd you use but an interstitual ad is usually a full screen ad, and not something you include in your widget tree I would think

Answer (score 1):

interstitial cant be show as widget ,
that's why its a throwing error . we have to show on click or on a timer.